# View is not binding correctly to ViewModel

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I cannot get the View to bind correctly to the ViewModel. When it displays, it only shows the string version of the ViewModel.

I have seen: [Setting Window.Content to ViewModel - simple data template not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108346/setting-window-content-to-viewmodel-simple-data-template-not-working). But the link is no longer available.

I'm trying to use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx, as a template.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="DemoApp.MainWindow"
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:DemoApp.ViewModel"
 xmlns:vw="clr-namespace:DemoApp.View">

<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:TestViewModel}">
       <vw:TestView/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ClosableTabItemTemplate">
       <DockPanel Width="120">
         <Button 
            Command="{Binding Path=CloseCommand}"
            Content="X"
            Cursor="Hand"
            DockPanel.Dock="Right"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"
            Width="16" Height="16"/>
         <ContentPresenter 
            Content="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
       </DockPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate x:Key="WorkspacesTemplate">
        <TabControl 
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ClosableTabItemTemplate}"
            Margin="4" />
    </DataTemplate>
 </Window.Resources>

   <DockPanel>
     <Border
        Grid.Column="2" 
        Style="{StaticResource MainBorderStyle}">
        <HeaderedContentControl 
        Content="{Binding Path=Workspaces}"
        ContentTemplate="{StaticResource WorkspacesTemplate}"
        Header="Workspaces"
        Style="{StaticResource MainHCCStyle}" />
     </Border>
   </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs
// ommitted for clarity. This is directing to the view model correctly. It's the binding between View and ViewModel that is not

TestView.xaml

```
public class TestViewModel : WorkspaceViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged, 
{
   public Model.Test _test;
   public string DisplayName {get; set;}
   public class TestViewModel(Model.Test t)
   {
      DisplayName = "Test Display Name";
      _model = t;
   }
   // INofifyPropertyChanged Members removed for clarity
}
```

Test.cs

```
public class Test
{
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}

    public static DisplayTest()
    {
       return new Test();
    }

}
```

Displays: 
DemoApp.ViewModel.TestViewModel;

However, when I go to the MainWindow.xaml and actually type in  into a DockPanel, it will display correctly...

Thank you!!

UPDATE:
MainWindowViewModel.cs Properties

```
public ReadOnlyCollection<CommandViewModel> Commands
    {
        get
        {
            if (_commands == null)
            {
                List<CommandViewModel> cmds = this.CreateCommands();
                _commands = new ReadOnlyCollection<CommandViewModel>(cmds);
            }
            return _commands;
        }
    }

public ObservableCollection<WorkspaceViewModel> Workspaces
    {
        get
        {
            if (_workspaces == null)
            {
                _workspaces = new ObservableCollection<WorkspaceViewModel>();
                _workspaces.CollectionChanged += this.OnWorkspacesChanged;
            }
            return _workspaces;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does your main view model expose a property that is an observable collection of TestViewModels?

Comment: Show us the MainWindowViewModel properties

Comment: where do you set or assign your DataContext for your View ?

Comment: So.. you have a collection of workspace view models, where do TestViewModel live?

Comment: TestViewModel inherits from the WorkspaceViewModel. As does the MainViewModel

Comment: Abin, the DataContext for the MainWindow is set on start up. The DataContext for the View should be being set in the MainWindowResources where it says <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:TestViewModel}"><vw:TestView/></DataTemplate>

Comment: Try changing `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TestViewModel}">` to `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:TestViewModel}">`

Comment: @AnjumSKhan I'm sure that's likely a typo in the question, as the code wouldn't compile without the namespace prefix.

Comment: Plz post a screen shot or an animated gif created using ScreenToGif utility

Comment: Yes, that is a typo from the transfer. I will change that in the display code. I apologize for that.

Comment: I cannot get a screen shot to you.
The window is just a normal WPF window. The content has the colored background. Header of the content displays Workspace. Directly underneath it reads: DemoApp.ViewModel.TestViewModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the View there was a Data Context Declared. This was confusing the binding it looks like. Once the Data Context in the View was removed and the MainWindowResourses kept the data context, the view is displayed as it should.